# Reading docx files with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, ms-word, docx

I can't find any documentation describing how to read docx files with python. Does anyone have an example they would supply please?

```
path = 'C:\'
fn = 'file.docx'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link:

http://www.darkcoding.net/software/printing-word-and-pdf-files-from-python/

```
from win32com import client
    import time

    word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

    def printWordDocument(filename):

        word.Documents.Open(filename)
        word.ActiveDocument.PrintOut()
        time.sleep(2)
        word.ActiveDocument.Close()

    word.Quit()
```